# Clean up code using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a big filter form and need to add conditions only if user fill the fields.

My current code is something like this:

```
var query = (from a in ....
             join b in ...
             join c in ...
             select new {a, b, c});

if (field1 != null) 
{
    query = query.where(x => x.a.Field == field1);
}

... and so on for every field
```

I´m looking for a way to create some method to make code simpler:

```
query = AddField1Condition(field1, query); //or anything like this...
```

How to write a method like this?
If I try to refactor using extract method, it gives the error:

> Extract method failed with following reasons :
>
> Parameters' type or return type cannot be an anonymous type : [query, return type]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> AddField1Condition(this IQueryable<T> query, string f1) where T:something
{
  if (f1==null)
    return query;
  return query.Where(x=>x.a.Field1 == f1);
}
```

Used like:

```
query = query.AddField1Condition(field1);
```

Comment: Upvoted (+1) from me except for the correctness of your answer, for the great explanation you gave regarding the execution plans and parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the extra `if` conditions. You could try something like the following:

```
var query = (from a in ....
             join b in ...
             join c in ...
             where (a.Field == field1 || field1 == null) 
             && (b.Field == field2 || field2 == null)
             select new {a, b, c});
```

Comment: This typically isn't a good approach because it can cause a lot of issues.  The approach the OP is using is much better.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Could you please mention a couple of these issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure.  It's sort of technical, but the major issue is parameter sniffing and query plan caching.  There are a number of articles on the web about it, but the basics can be found here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ The short is that because the queries will be parameterized, the same plan will be used for both when field1 is null and when it is not null if you use `WHERE (@p is null or Field=@p)` when really two separate plans need to be made to run optimally.

Comment: A slightly longer explanation is that when the query first gets run, it will use parameter sniffing to determine the best way to execute that query based on the value that is passed in first.  That plan is then cached and reused for all further queries, even when the value changes.  I've seen queries that should run in microseconds take more than 60 seconds to run because of this, and changing the queries to the way the OP has done them fixes the problem because the actual text of the query changes, which then causes SQL Server to cache different plans for each.

Comment: Of course, some of this is dependent on the ORM (or version of the ORM) and the database driver (and version of the database driver) as well, as some of them will actually identify the null parameter, and remove it from the query before passing it on to the SQL server, but many/most don't.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Very good point ! Thanks for you reply. I have overlooked completely this :(.